# Google Chrome flickering over Remote Desktop (RDP)

Tags: windows-server-2012, google-chrome

I am using Chrome on Windows Server 2012 machine via RDP, but I am noticing a weird issue where Google Chrome will flicker (with black patches). Is this a known issue? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using NVIDIA video card in your terminal server?

Source of the problem is somewhere in how direct draw works with Nvidia drivers and RDP frame buffer.

Patch is to remove at all NVIDIA drivers.

May be somebody found a solution?